# Integration by substitution: $\int -\frac 1a \frac{f(ar)}{f'(ar)}.r\ dr$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

[image]

How can I proceed to find the indefinite integral of the above form where $f(ar)$ is a function of $r$,  and $a$ is a constant?

I tried integration by substitution (with another random variable, say $t$), but unable to replace $r$ in terms of $t$ (as the function is not specified). Is there any other approach to solve this?

Thanks in Advance.